# blastn -mt_mode 1 -num_threads 24 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'

Tags: bioinformatics, blast

When I was running blastn v2.12.0 with multithreaded mode (-num_thread 24), split by query(-mt_mode 1), I have the following error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
what():  basic_string::_M_create

for a supercomputer (RHEL 7/cent OS), this happened but for a self-owned ubuntu v18.0.4, this did not happen.

Blast team do not respond so I posted it here.

Many Thanks

Comment: by the way it is the -task blastn algorithm, the slower version for low identity matches.

Comment: Could have something to do with your server configuration. Some processes might not support multithreading across multiple nodes.

Comment: This is not multiple nodes but only one node.